# How to get the data from a collection array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have this Collection Array in `Laravel` that is from the database
[image]

```
 public function getdiagnosistally(){

      $jsonData = ListBuilder::all()->pluck('listdata');
        $res = $jsonData->contains('Test');
        dd($jsonData,$res);
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to count the occurrences of the following data inside the collection.

I have tried using below contain method but it does not give me a true result even if there is Test inside the Collection.

```
 $res = $jsonData->contains('Test');
```

I have also tried using count method but it only gives me the total amount of the collection not the count of Test which is 2 but the result gives me 6.

```
 $res = $jsonData->count('Test');
```

[image]

The end result i was aiming is like it will be counting the occurrences of Test from the json data.

for example :-

```
Test = 2
Test child 1 = 4
```

Would you be able to advice how i can fix it?

Comment: That's an array of strings mate. There's no way to check the actual data without using `json_decode`. Ofc you can hack it by doing something like `stristr` but that's just silly.

Comment: In addition to @Andrew's comment: You've got 5 occurrences of "Test", not 2. So even if you are able to fix your code, your results would seem "wrong" to you.

Comment: You have an array of strings. You just need to count the occurrences. As Andrew pointed out. You must decode the JSON. This is not laravel related but rather a PHP question.

Comment: thanks for the input, will note them down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a Collection, you could solve it functionally using [filter](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter) and [array_count_values](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-filter).

1. First we decode the json to array and wrap it in a Collection.
2. Then we filter to keep only the values containing the string 'Test'
3. We use flatMap to get all these values in a single array
4. So we can finally use `array_count_values` to get the desired result.

code:

```
$testValues = $jsonData->flatMap(function($json) {
    $data = collect(json_decode($json, true)['checklist']);
    return $data->filter(function($item) {
        return str_contains($item, 'Test');
    });
});

$result = array_count_values($testValues->all());

dd($result);
```

Note that in this solution I assumed the first level of the json is always "checklist". If not, you have to loop over it.

Comment: Thank you winkbrace for the detailed explanation. I'll try the sample code you have provide and I will check how to properly use the filter and array_count_method. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You count the occurrences manually by iterating over collection and JSON data converted to an array.

I've just tested this and it will work for the data format you're using:

```
$count = 0;
$jsonData->map(function($i) use(&$count) {
    $i = json_decode($i, true);
    array_map(function($i) use(&$count) {
        if (str_contains($i, 'Test')) $count++;
    }, $i['checklist']);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! will check this out and try to implement

Answer (score 0):

For instance your database table name is "Checklist" and "test" is a column.

$count = Checklist::Select('checklist.test')->count();

You can also use where if that's the condition
->where('checklist_id', $request->id)